# Drush Site Install does not populate table prefix

Tags: multi-sites

```
sudo drush site-install standard -y --db-prefix='alaska_' --db-su='postgres' 
--db-url=pgsql://drupaldbuser:password@localhost:5432/drupal 
--account-name='admin' --account-pass='admin' --site-name='alaska' 
--sites-subdir='alaska.jobcorps.gov'
```

This command does not populate the database with tables that have the table prefix.  This prevents us from installing Drupal 8 multi-site on a single database using Drush.

I've tried renaming the tables and then proceeding with the next sub-site install.  This fails because drush drops all tables when it runs subsequent installs on the same database.

I've also tried

```
install_settings_form.pgsql_prefix='alaska_'
```

Tried multiple versions of Drush.  Currently on `9.0-dev` to see if that has a fix in it.

Answer (score 0):

For the problem of dropped tables, you can use --db-drop-existing-tables=FALSE.

I'm looking for an answer to the prefix problem too ...